# Magento - Add category name as a classname to list item in main navigation

Tags: magento

In the main menu, I'd like to add the name of each category as a classname to the list item, for example

```
<li class="level0 nav-3 brands level-top parent">
<a href="http://www.examplesite.co.uk/brands.html" class="level-top">
  <span>Brands</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The place the navigation is rendered can be found in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml`, which is located in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation`. The first argument passed to the function is the category, I imagine you can pull the name out of that and add it into the `$classes` array (~line 247 in Magento 1.7). You should of course consider creating your own module and rewriting that block, rather than editing the core file.